# GAMs (mgcv) binomial vs negative binomial vs zero inflated poisson

Tags: r, distribution, modeling, gam, mgcv

I am modeling coastal dolphin distribution with GAMs (package mgcv) and because most "events" modelled result in no sightings- the model has many zeros.
The zero-inflated poisson model seemed to work well with the data but gam.summary was not able to provide an R-squared value, and deviance explained resulted in a negative value.
I moved on to attempting negative binomial but i am unsure whether to model presence-absence data or to model the number of individuals in a sighting as "count data".

1. Any ideas in regards to the zero inflated poisson errors?
2. Any recommendations on modeling negative binomial as presence/absence or count?

Many thanks!

Comment: This belongs on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) and will probably be migrated there soon (one more vote from a sufficiently high-rep user). R-squared values are quite tricky for zero-inflated GLMs, regardless of what package/framework you use. It would help to give a little bit more information; what is the proportion of zero/non-zero observations, what is the mean and range of the non-zero counts?

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the response! Why is this better suited for cross validated? is that a more appropriate forum for statistics question where as stack overflow is for coding? (I honestly don't know and would like to post in the correct place next time).
My data has approx 20,000 rows, of with only 304 are not-zero. This data is a result of many years of ecological surveys, and the over-load of zeros is in part real, and in part due to the way i had to segment the data due to the surveying methodology. the mean of the counts is 4.9 and the data ranges from 1 - 20 (dolphins sighted in a group)

Comment: It's been a while, this kind of fell through the cracks. If you haven't already posted there, I would suggest deleting this post and re-posting on CV. (You are correct: SO is for coding, CV is for stats questions.)  The info you've provided in the comment should go into your post on CV ...